# Time Limit Exceeded error in C code . How do I overcome it?

Tags: c, error-handling, goto

I was trying to convert this piece of code to a code that uses just gotos,but I keep getting the Time limit error when I try to run it on the online IDEs,and when I try to run on my console it doesn't even react or print errors.

here is the original code:

```
void sort (int skip, int ∗A, int length) {
    for (int n = length ; n > 1 ; n−−) {
        int i = 0 ;
        while (true) {
            if (skip == 0 && i < n−1) {
                if (A[i] > A[i +1]) {
                    A[i] = A[i] ^ A[i+1];
                    A[i +1] = A[i +1] ^ A[i] ;
                    A[i] = A[i] ^ A[i+1] ;
                }
            }else
                break ;
            i++;
       }
   }
}
```

and this is the transformed code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort(int skip,int *A,int length){
    int n=length;
    int i,temp,temp2;
Lcond:
    if(n<=1) goto Lend;
Lbody:
    i=0;
Lcond_:
    if(skip!=0) goto Lelse;
    temp=n-1;
    if(i>=temp) goto Lelse;
Lbody_:
    temp2=i+1;
    if(A[i]>A[temp2]) goto Lbody__;
    i++;
    goto Lcond_;
Lbody__:
    A[i]=A[i]^A[temp2];
    A[temp2]=A[temp2]^A[i];
    A[i]=A[i]^A[temp2];
    i++;
    goto Lcond_;
Lelse:
    goto Lcond;
Lend:
    return;
}
int main(){
    int skip=0;
    int A[5]={3,5,1,4,2};
    int length=5;
    sort(skip,A,length);
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
            printf("%d\t",A[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: *I was trying to convert this piece of code to a code that uses just gotos* - Why???

Comment: I want to learn about the goto  construct .Plus it is a good step to convert the code to assembly

Comment: You should **fix** your code.

Comment: @Antti what do you mean?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't *ever* use the xor swap - if the compiler **is not smart**, *it doesn't know to replace the xor swap with swap that uses an intermediate variable*.

Comment: There's very little need to learn about the goto construct, and why do you think you need to convert it into assembly.  The xor-swapping algorithm isn't very sensible, either — it is a bad way to do the swap.

Comment: So you have learnt about `goto` very well now. The lesson is that it is very hard to follow and debug and thus you should avoid it.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala worth mentioning that XOR swap will give your zeroes if the values being swapped are already equal.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons hem?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala If you are trying to swap A and B with XOR swap, well the first step is `A XOR B`.  If A = B, then you get `A XOR A` which is 0.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I think you have a misunderstanding about the XOR swapping.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm

Comment: @Antti so should I just use a normal swap ?

Comment: @Eugene I can tell :)

Comment: But  xor swap will fail if trying to swap the same *object* with itself, not the same value. It can happen when working with arrays...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Oh, okay, I see what you mean.  Important distinction.

Comment: @Antti why should the compiler replace the xor swap with the intuitive swap?

Comment: Yes, you should use an intermediate variable. It will result in faster code. The one that @EugeneSh. mentions cannot happen in *your* code because of the `+ 1`, the zeroing can only happen when you're swapping the an object with *itself*, not 2 distinct objects having the same value. Nevertheless, you should unlearn it.

Comment: @donpwner the intuitive swap is *faster*.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I see thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program never ends because the only `goto Lend` is in `Lcond: if(n<=1) goto Lend;`, and `n` never changes, so the program keeps looping endlessly. You need an end condition.

Comment: Or from the perspective of transforming the original code to the new code, the `n--` in the control statement of the `for` loop has not been transformed into anything.

Comment: Oh I see Thanks!

Comment: Thanks,that did it . I also fixed some other mistakes